# how to show data from json to ui-grid in angular ui-grid

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, django, angular-ui-grid

I am getting this json from django and I want to show this in angular ui-grid but I am getting error:

```
Error: colDef.name or colDef.field property is required
preprocessColDef@http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/buddy/js/ui-grid.js:3771:1
buildColumns/<@http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/buddy/js/ui-grid.js:3630:7
buildColumns@http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/buddy/js/ui-grid.js:3629:5
dataWatchFunction@http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/buddy/js/ui-grid.js:2749:27
$watchCollectionAction@http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/buddy/js/angular.js:15693:13
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/buddy/js/angular.js:15826:23
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/buddy/js/angular.js:16097:13
done@http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/buddy/js/angular.js:10546:36
completeRequest@http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/buddy/js/angular.js:10744:7
requestLoaded@http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/buddy/js/angular.js:10685:1
```

I want to show only attributes from "fields"

the json is:

```
[{"fields": {"joiningtime": null, "boozprofileId": 1, "userId": 1, "likeStatus": true}, "model": "buddy.guestentry", "pk": 1}, {"fields": {"joiningtime": null, "boozprofileId": 1, "userId": 1, "likeStatus": true}, "model": "buddy.guestentry", "pk": 2}, {"fields": {"joiningtime": "2015-10-18T15:53:58.243Z", "boozprofileId": 12, "userId": 3, "likeStatus": true}, "model": "buddy.guestentry", "pk": 3}, {"fields": {"joiningtime": "2015-10-18T15:54:24.055Z", "boozprofileId": 8, "userId": 3, "likeStatus": true}, "model": "buddy.guestentry", "pk": 4}, {"fields": {"joiningtime": null, "boozprofileId": 3, "userId": 1, "likeStatus": true}, "model": "buddy.guestentry", "pk": 5}, {"fields": {"joiningtime": null, "boozprofileId": 3, "userId": 1, "likeStatus": true}, "model": "buddy.guestentry", "pk": 6}, {"fields": {"joiningtime": null, "boozprofileId": 3, "userId": 1, "likeStatus": true}, "model": "buddy.guestentry", "pk": 7}, {"fields": {"joiningtime": null, "boozprofileId": 3, "userId": 1, "likeStatus": true}, "model": "buddy.guestentry", "pk": 8}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you receive indicates that you not have defined column definitions for the UI Grid, or perhaps not have defined them properly. Simply refer to the nested `fields` attributes as `fields.<attributeName>` :

```js
//the JSON from above 
$scope.gridOptions.data = [{"fields": {"joiningtime": null, "boozprofileId": ....}];

$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
   {name: 'fields.joiningtime' }, 
   {name: 'fields.boozprofileId' }, 
   {name: 'fields.userId' },
   {name: 'fields.likeStatus' } 
];
```

demo ->  **http://plnkr.co/edit/KXvES4G64RVwneFbZzV2?p=preview**

---

Remember to target the right controller. You have both `IndexCtrl` and `ajax` :

```
<div ng-controller="ajax">
   <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-cellNav class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: now I am  getting error : colDef.name or colDef.field property is required

Comment: @focode - you did that before too - "_colDef.name or colDef.field property is required_" - it would be a lot easier if you showed your code, perhaps you have a problem with the markup. Did you copy the scheme from the plnkr? It should work right away, like with a `$http`.

Comment: I was not able to copy past it here , here is the github link for it ...controller name is ajax: https://github.com/focode/buddy2/blob/master/src/static/buddy/js/main.js

Comment: @focode - thank you for that. It works with `$http` too, reduced code of what you are doing -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/ITKTq1WYRgOCbD7W0Ms7?p=preview** but see update to the answer, could not find the specific HTML file on your github, but something tells me you have forgot to target the right controller.

Comment: It great help from you david, I was able to see the grid with header but I am not able to see the data in it. my html file is this :https://github.com/focode/buddy2/blob/master/src/buddy/templates/guestList.html and their is no error in console, doing some further research I figured that I am able to get data from the url that you have mentioned but not from my webservices

Comment: In console your webservice resonse is like :guestdata::1[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] but my webservice response is printed as json

Comment: @focode, this is because I just copypasted your code, when you are using aString+someJSONobject you get this, you should use `console.log("guestdata::", $scope.guestdata);` or `console.dir($scope.guestdata)` - but this is irrelevant, again : Change that `MainCtrl1` to `ajax`, this is there your UI Grid definitions is!!!!

Comment: I was able to se my data in grid just by changing this line : $scope.guestdata = JSON.parse(response); It would have not been possible with out your help david

Answer (score 1):

Just in case David's answer didn't helped for you:

Try Removing

```
$scope.gridOptions.data = [{"fields": {"joiningtime": null, "boozprofileId": ....}];

$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
   {name: 'fields.joiningtime' }, 
   {name: 'fields.boozprofileId' }, 
   {name: 'fields.userId' },
   {name: 'fields.likeStatus' } 
];
```

from after `JSON received` place and put it in starting of controller function.

I mean intialize it at very beginning and then just update `data` when you receive `JSON response`

```
$scope.gridOptions.data = response.data
```